# What is the Wix heat.exe command line switch "-directoryid" doing?

Tags: wix

I was not able to find any sufficient documentation about what the "-directoryid" command line switch of the heat tool is good for.  Can someone please explain what this switch can be used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Heat documentation [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html), the -directoryid switch is used to override the Id attribute of the generated directory element.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  That's how far I came on my own.  I would know what this switch is good for, eg. with real world sample to get a better understanding of it's use.